# Expect script clause evaluation

Tags: expect

In my expect script, my goal is to send a command to show the properties of the two processors on a motherboard. Please assume the remote logging in is successful. It's where the send clause variables are not evaluated successfully.

1. I have a procedure and a variable:
   set showcpu "show -d properties /SYS/MB/P\r"
2. I created a while loop to execute do a "send" if the "cpu" count starts at 0 and less   than 2.

   ```
   set cpu 0

   while { $cpu < 2 } {
     expect {
       -re $prompt {send "${showcpu}${cpu}\r"; }
       timeout {
         my_puts "ILOM prompt timeout error-2" [ list $fh1 $fh3 stdout ]
         exit 1
       }
     }

     set cpu [ expr {$cpu + 1} ]
   }
   ```

The execution result is this:

```
[BL0/SP]-> show -d properties /SYS/MB/P
show: Invalid target /SYS/MB/P

[BL0/SP]-> 0
Invalid command '0' - type help for a list of commands.
```

I wanted the script to combine the value `$showcpu` with `$cpu` and it should look like this:

```
show -d properties /SYS/MB/P0 and show -d properties /SYS/MB/P1.
```

Could someone please educate me on what I need to do to accomplish that?

Comment: It's not necessary to apologize for your question.  It also helps to read the formatting guide, particularly when you're pasting in chunks of code.

Comment: Can you show us where you're setting `showcpu`?  It looks like you have have an erroneous eol in that string.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `${showcpu}` itself already contains "\r" (according to 1.).
Either define it without "\r":

```
set showcpu "show -d properties /SYS/MB/P"
```

or use `string trim` (http://wiki.tcl.tk/10174):

```
send "[string trim ${showcpu}]${cpu}\r"
```

I would recommend to trim the white spaces on the place where the variable is set, not at the places where the variable is used.